# Pymodbus in Docker connection error [Errno99]

Tags: docker, dockerfile, pymodbus

I am trying to make the Pymodbus examples work in docker so I built this dockerfile for the client:

```
FROM ubuntu

RUN  apt-get update -y

RUN apt-get install -y python3.7 \
 && apt-get install -y python3-pymodbus

ADD synchronous_client.py sincclient.py
```

where synchronous_client.py is the [example](https://pymodbus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/example/synchronous_client.html) given by Pymodbus.
And i have the same for the synchronous_server.

I am not using DockerCompose yet, so i'm just  in 2 different command prompts. The server is apparently on but when I try to run the client on the docker client image i get this:

```
> root@2697b6089821:/# python3 sincclient.py 2020-06-04 12:36:48,674
> MainThread      ERROR    sync           :206      Connection to
> (localhost, 5020) failed: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
> 2020-06-04 12:36:48,674 MainThread      DEBUG    sincclient     :85   
> Reading Coils 2020-06-04 12:36:48,674 MainThread      ERROR    sync   
> :206      Connection to (localhost, 5020) failed: [Errno 99] Cannot
> assign requested address Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "sincclient.py", line 166, in <module>
>     run_sync_client()   File "sincclient.py", line 86, in run_sync_client
>     rr = client.read_coils(1, 1, unit=UNIT)   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pymodbus/client/common.py", line 48,
> in read_coils
>     return self.execute(request)   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pymodbus/client/sync.py", line 107, in
> execute
>     raise ConnectionException("Failed to connect[%s]" % (self.__str__())) pymodbus.exceptions.ConnectionException: Modbus
> Error: [Connection] Failed to connect[ModbusTcpClient(localhost:5020)]
> root@2697b6089821:/# python3 sincclient.py 2020-06-04 12:51:18,283
> MainThread      ERROR    sync           :206      Connection to
> (localhost, 5020) failed: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
> 2020-06-04 12:51:18,284 MainThread      DEBUG    sincclient     :85   
> Reading Coils 2020-06-04 12:51:18,284 MainThread      ERROR    sync   
> :206      Connection to (localhost, 5020) failed: [Errno 99] Cannot
> assign requested address Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "sincclient.py", line 166, in <module>
>     run_sync_client()   File "sincclient.py", line 86, in run_sync_client
>     rr = client.read_coils(1, 1, unit=UNIT)   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pymodbus/client/common.py", line 48,
> in read_coils
>     return self.execute(request)   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pymodbus/client/sync.py", line 107, in
> execute
>     raise ConnectionException("Failed to connect[%s]" % (self.__str__())) pymodbus.exceptions.ConnectionException: Modbus
> Error: [Connection] Failed to connect[ModbusTcpClient(localhost:5020)]
```

I am new into this so I have not a clear idea of what to do but think it might be something to do with the network mode of docker?